# Calculate conditional probability with given density function

Tags: probability

Suppose that waiting in queue at the post office (in hours) has probability density function:

\begin{equation}
f(x) =
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{3}{8}(2 - \sqrt{x}) & \text{if } x \in [0, 4],\\
        0 & \textrm{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Question:
Given the information that **we are already waiting 1 hour**, what is probability **we will wait more than another 1 hour?**

My idea is to calculate waiting for the first hour first, which is:

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{3}{8}(2 - \sqrt{x}) \,dx  = \frac{1}{2}$$

Then I think the right approach is to calculate probability of waiting more than 2 hours, which is:

$$1 - \int_{0}^{2} \frac{3}{8}(2 - \sqrt{x}) \,dx  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{2}$$

The last thing we want to calculate probability of waiting more than 2 hours conditional on already waiting 1 hour, which should be probability of waiting 1 hour and at the same time waiting more than 2 hours (first is a subset of the second) divided by probability of waiting one hour, which is:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}} \approx 0.41$$

I am not experienced in probability so would appreciate if there are any mistakes in my reasoning.

Thanks.

Comment: The probability is one as written; that is, you want $P(X > 1 \mid X \geq 1)$ and this is $1.$ Although, your approach seems to indicate you actually want $P(X > 2 \mid X \geq 1).$

Comment: @WilliamM. yes it might be phrased odd, but this is what I mean: You are waiting one hour and still waiting, you want to know with what probability you will wait more than one additional hour. So the question is with what probability will you wait more than 2 hours if you have already waited for 1 hour.

Comment: Assuming you are after $P(X > 2 \mid X \geq 1),$ I got the same result as you.

Comment: @WilliamM. thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a bit on what you've done. You want to compute $P(X > 2 | X > 1)$ which, using the definition of conditional probability, is equivalent to $\frac{P(X>2,X>1)}{P(X>1)}=\frac{P(X>2)}{P(X>1)}$ since waiting one hour is a subset of waiting two hours. Then plugging in the integrals you computed you get your answer which is correct.

Comment: That is not Bayes' rule (althought, to be fair, equivalent to it), that is the definition of conditional probability.